# jQuery - Create new div for each object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, for-loop

I have an html code block

```
<div class="modal-comment-content">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="/defaultpic.jpg" width="100" class="img-circle"></a></li>
        <li>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#" class="comment_username">John D.</a></li>
            <li class="comment_created_at">~ 4 hours ago</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="comment_comment">This is a completely random sentence. This is the second sentence. Closing sentence right here.</p>
      <hr>
</div>
```

I have a for loop that is iterating over an array of objects.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
    {
      var user = json[i].user.first_name + ' ' + json[i].user.last_name.charAt(0) + '.';
      var comment     = json[i].comment;
      var created_at  = json[i].created_at;

    }
```

I would like to use the html code block as a 'template' for each iteration of the array objects. Any ideas on how this is done? Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Angular JS, there is always the NG Repeat Tag and tie the HTML Code (which is your template) to a model. Here is the documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

If you're just working on making quick hack, and use of frameworks is not to your interest, you can always do something like this

```
// create the template variable using your div content and some special tokens
var template = '<div class="modal-comment-content">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="%USER_IMAGE%" width="100" class="img-circle"></a></li>
    <li>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="#" class="comment_username">%USERNAME%</a></li>
        <li class="comment_created_at">%CREATED_AT%</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="comment_comment">%COMMENT%</p>
  <hr>
</div>';

var jLen  = json.length;
var parentDiv = $('#parentDiv');

// create and attach a new 'Div' to some parent
// using the template, replacing the tokens with dynamic values from the list.
for (var i = 0; i < jLen; ++i)
{
  var user = json[i].user.first_name + ' ' + json[i].user.last_name.charAt(0) + '.';
  var comment     = json[i].comment;
  var created_at  = json[i].created_at;
  var divContent = template.replace('%COMMENT%', comment).replace('%CREATED_AT%', created_at).replace('%USERNAME%', user);

  parentDiv.append(divContent);
}
```

Comment: Can this be achieved with pure jquery? I've never seen this done before. Can you explain what the %COMMENT% for example, means in var template?

Comment: It is pure jQuery, the %% string is just a way to find/replace values inside the template. Nothing special about it, it is just something would wouldn't normally use in a string. You could use '@&COMMENT^%' if you liked.

Comment: As Beaverus said, Its just a nomenclature i chose to make the 'replace' easy. You can choose any you like, or use concatenation (which is arguably faster, however harder to read code wise)

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches, depending on the specifications of your project:

### HTML5 Templates

If you know your users fall under [capable browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template) you can use the new HTML templating functionality.

### JS Templates

If your project is large enough and you know you'll be using this kind of code often you could use something like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to handle templating in an easy and maintainable way.

### jQuery DOM strings

The quickest (and dirtiest) way is to create a function that returns a built HTML string and then you can attach it to the DOM:

```
function buildCard(person) {
    return '<div class="card"><h2>'+person.name+'</h2><p>'+person.details+'</p></div>';
}
```